# How to have write permissions on an already shared folder?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

The problem is that my users can not change files in a shared folder (on a mounted drive as folder under D: drive).

These are all the steps that I have tried and are still applicable: (sorry for the lengthy post)

1 -  I have created a shared folder on a windows 2008 R2 and I manage it with the files services role.

[image]

2 - Using SMB share settings, I gave access to all domain users.

[image]

3 - Right click the folder - selecting share with - again - giving every user access

[image]
[image]

4 - Right click the folder -> properties: in the sharing: I made sure all users have access.

[image]
[image]

5 - advanced sharing - also have correct settings

[image]

6 - on security settings of the folder properties, again - domain users have full control

[image]

7 - I am checking a certain domain member (test) to see if he gets correct effective permissions

[image]

- so, assuming all is correrct, user: test - should have full access to a folder located inside: BUILDS - not.

Getting effective permissions for user test on the folder gives me read access permissions only:

[image]

My question:

1. Why am I gettings wrong permissions for the user test on the folder?
2. What settings do I need, so users can have full access to the folder/files even if it's not them as the owners.

Comment: It's a mounted drive - could that be an issue? (added to question)

Comment: Very possibly - the NTFS permissions of the mount point (i.e. the folder) are not the same as the NTFS permissions of the root of the mounted drive. Check those in Disk Manager on the server

Comment: Eureka - thanks - had to give the drive the correct settings in the disk management window. feel free to post as answer - where were you 3 hours ago :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a mounted drive as you mention in your comment:

The NTFS permissions of a mount point (i.e. the folder) are not the same as the NTFS permissions of the root of the mounted drive. Check those in Disk Manager on the server.

It's very probable that the share management console is showing you the NTFS permissions of the mount point, not the mounted drive.